# Adapting an I2C FRAM chip to an SRAM-like parallel interface

Tags: parallel, sram, non-volatile-memory

I have a project that requires a parallel interface non-volatile RAM. I had hoped to use an FRAM, however the only parallel FRAMs seem to much larger in capacity (and more importantly, price) than I need/want. On the serial side, things are much cheaper (even more so with EEPROMs). Digikey sells 8KiB I2C FRAMs for ~$1. That would be about perfect, were it not for the serial interface. What I'm curious about is whether there exist any kind of off-the-shelf solution for interfacing an I2C memory to a parallel interface

Comment: Why does it have to be a parallel interface?  Can you add an I2C interface to your MCU?

Comment: +1 for using KiB

Comment: It doesn't theoretically have to: the project is a kind of pedagogical computer that I want to have as simple of a programming model as possible. A memory-mapped parallel interface that is as simple as reading or writing to an address is attractive towards this end

Comment: What access time do you need? I2C is slow compared to any parallel interface.

Comment: This would be for a slow 8-bit CPU. Probably no more than 5mhz or so. There are cheap SPI FRAMs as well which would work fine too if a solution could exist for them

Answer (score 3):

This may be a case where a small microcontroller would do the job. The issue would be dealing with the I2C time overhead - your host will have to wait sometimes. You could mitigate that with a caching approach.

Does your host have GPIO? Then you could bit-bang the I2C. This may be acceptable if your I/O needs are low.

Comment: A parallel interface to an 8KiB, byte-oriented, RAM would require at least 22 GPIO lines...13 address, 8 data, and a R/W. I'm not sure that qualifies as a "small microcontroller".

Comment: The bigger issue is dealing with the i/o transaction latency. So it likely needs to be a different programmer’s model - a block-oriented transaction over an 8-bit port, like NAND flash. This wouldn’t support XIP, but it would kind of work. SPI would be preferable I think as it would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a project that requires a parallel interface non-volatile RAM.

So use some parallel non-volatile RAM! Battery-backed SRAMs are available from [Cypress](https://www.cypress.com/products/nvsram-nonvolatile-sram), [ST](https://www.st.com/en/memories/zeropower.html), and [Maxim](https://para.maximintegrated.com/search.mvp?fam=memory&489=NV%20SRAM&tree=memory) (formerly Dallas); most of them are in packages compatible with standard DIP SRAM.

Comment: Or don't use "some parallel non-volatile RAM!". Batteries are to be avoided: bulky, inconvenient to handle and dispose of, goes flat and costly. FRAM avoids all that, it's in tiny packages and cheap. This is not a solution to the asked question so downvoting, I'm afraid.